# JQuery .find and .html(alertBox) not working with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AJAX contact form with Bootstrap theme. 
Here I have to tried to add alert box like this

```
$('#contact-form').find('.sashikanta').html(alertBox);
```

But the selector cannot able to find the class .sashikanta. In the place of the above simple alert is working fine and the email form working.

Below is my JS code.

```
$(function () {
$('#contact-form').validator();
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
  if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "mail.php";
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;


                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';


                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {

                        $('#contact-form').find('.sashikanta').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Please suggest I did not find anything through Firebug.

Comment: Please add your HTML code of #contact-form.

Comment: can you post the html-output?